# Zephir Language Parse Exception

Tags: zephir

I am trying to compile the below code in zephir language and it gives me Parse error.
I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
 public static function calculateDiscrepancy(tpImpr, liImpressions, defaults) {
    var numeratorx = 1-(tpImpr + defaults);
    if numeratorx != 0 && liImpressions != 0 {
          return (double)(numeratorx / liImpressions) * 100;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
}
```

## Error

```
Zephir\ParseException: Syntax error in /var/www/vhosts/app/advertisingcalculator.zep on line 58

     var numeratorx = 1-(tpImpr + defaults);
-----------------------^
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
let numeratorx = 1 - (tpImpr + defaults);
```

Edit: removed asterisks. Leave a space between `1` and the operator `-`, and another space between the operator `-` and the left parenthesis `(`.

`var` is only for declarations and the value must be static, then you can set a dynamic value with `let`:

```
var numeratorx; // or var numeratorx = 1;
let numeratorx = 1 - (tpImpr + defaults);
```